# Error message is not rendering | url validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to render the error message in my HTML form when a non-url is submitted, as I need to be able to easily adjust the position and apply a CSS style.

The reason I am going through this and not just simply using `type=url`, as I do not like the standard chrome validation error message, and I want to throw my own beneath my form.

Currently, no error message is showing when a non-url is submitted, and there are no errors in my console. Any thoughts?

**HTML**

```html
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
    <div class="inner-form">
        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
            <div class="svg-wrapper">
                <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="24"
                    height="24"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                    <path
                        d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "
                    ></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <input
                id="search"
                name="url"
                placeholder="Paste a domain here"
                type="url"
                required
                oninvalid="onInvalid(event)"
            />
        </div>

        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <button
                id="button"
                class="btn-search"
                onclick="searchIt()"
                value="press"
                type="submit"
            >
                SEARCH
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL.</p>
</form>
```

**JS**

```js
function onInvalid(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerText = "Yikes! That's not a valid URL";
}
```

**CSS**

```css
#errorMessage {
   display: none;
   color: #EB7051;
   font-size: 15px;
}
```

Could it be because the `display: none` ? I only want it to show when a non valid url (does not contain http:// or https://), and then disappear when a valid url is submitted

Edit of desired result:

[image]

Comment: Change display:none to some other display (say block).which would make the element visible. Also consider putting console.log in the code and trace the exact execution path

Comment: @vvs but then it is visible the entire time

Comment: I only want it to show up when a non valid url is submitted

Comment: Looked at again. There is a much simpler way to override the message using custom validity. Please have a look at this article https://dzone.com/articles/custom-validation-messages. In your oninvalid function you need to set the custom validity message rather than playing with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments, I was able to set up a sample which allows showing a specific tag placed right after the affected input. You may want to club it with the javascript you already have in case you want to modify the message in the tag
Please see below.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.errorMessage {
   display: none;
   color: #EB7051;
   font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus:invalid + p {
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="Submit" >
        <div class="inner-form">
             <div class="input-field first-wrap">                    
                  <input id="search" name="url" placeholder="Paste a domain here" type="url" required />
                  <p class="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL.</p>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                 <button id="button" class="btn-search" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The example above is based on ideas found here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-styling-form-input-validity

Comment: Maybe I led to some confision. It is not the wording I want to change, but I do to want Chrome's own validation error message. Please see the screenshot I added for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Will add some more thoughts to my answer

Comment: please check now. I have been able use a custom <p> placed right after the <input> and modify style based on CSS pseudo selectors.